# Minecraft animals growing up

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I breed animals, after one game day when the baby's grown up, if they are in a fence cage thing, they always seem to be on the outside? Is that supposed to happen?

Comment: What is the question? It is a bit unclear what you want to know.

Comment: Basically, if i bred pigs, the baby animal would have its head sticking out of the fence and if it grows when it is doing that it ends up outside of the fence? I dont understand why.

Comment: I'm sorry, as a non native English speaker I really don't understand what you are saying. Are the animals escaping from the cages?

Comment: As in, when they put there heads through the fence, if they grow up when there head is through the fence, then they appear on the outside..... I dont know how to explain it any better sorry.

Answer (score 1):

When the animals fully mature, their model is replaced with the larger 'adult' version.
When the small baby model is halfway through the fence, and it changes to the large, it detects that the model is more than halfway through it and appropriately places it outside.

I recommend building a secondary enclosure around your initial enclosure to prevent them escaping.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes small creatures (including baby monsters) can squeeze through thin blocks like fences or doors especially if they are pushed by other creatures.